# How get display value of checkbox in a checkbox group?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using APEX 21.1. I have a checkbox group whose list of values is retrieved using a query...

```
select disease, id from history;
```

The query returns many checkboxes. I have another textarea item. I need to get the display value for any checkbox whenever it's checked and set item HISTORY to that value. How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Describing a how-to would be so much easier if you had provided some example page item names and example data. So, lets call your checkbox group `P10_CHECKBOX` and your textarea `P10_TEXT`.

Usually, your checkbox group will save the item ids as a colon seperated list, like this: `3:4:5`

To display the corresponding display values, make a dynamic action on change on your item `P10_CHECKBOX`.

[image]

Then, use an `action` of type `Execute PL/SQL Code` to fetch the display values of your items.
The code could look like this:

```
select listagg(disease,chr(10)) within group (order by disease) into :P10_TEXT
from history h
join table(apex_string.split_numbers(:P10_CHECKBOX,':')) t on (h.id = t.column_value);
```

`apex_string.split_numbers` will convert your colon list into an actual "table" with the column `column_value` you can use in the join clause. `listagg` will do the actual concatenation and will work up to a couple thousand characters. `chr(10)` is an ordinary line break and will have your items be shown line by line, but any other seperator will do.

Last step is to set up `P10_CHECKBOX` in your `Items to submit` and `P10_TEXT` in your `Items to return`.

[image]

Now, whenever you click a checkbox, the textarea will be updated immediately.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it with the base methods APEX provides. If you would want to do it in JavaScript, then you would have to read/parse the HTML generated by APEX, as the item value itself only contains the IDs, and not your display values.